# Ubuntu 14.04 Software Center sync doesn't work

Tags: software-center, sync, 14.04

I just put a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 on my desktop and laptop.
But I can't get the Software Center sync to work.

I clicked File, Sync Between Computers and on each computer I see the own system, but not the other. In the bottom it says 'To sync with another computer, choose "Sync Between Computers" from that computer.' I already did that.

How does Software Center sync between computers?
Does it still use Ubuntu One for this? In  other posts on this forum I found reference to that. But One will be closed down, so I canceled my One account...

Opening https://software-center.ubuntu.com/subscriptions/ gives me a list of purchased software, that I can also see in Software Center itself.

I hope someone can give me a clue where to look for the problem.

Comment: See [Shutting down Ubuntu-One](http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/). Software Center Sync used the Ubuntu One cloud services. As per the notice above, Ubuntu One is not included with Wubuntu 14.04. Therefore software center sync cannot work.

Comment: How will they make the sync work now that U1 is no longer available?

Comment: I asked the same question on LaunchPad (see https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+question/258622) with no luck.