# How will they make the Software Centre sync now that U1 is no longer available?

Tags: software-center, ubuntu-one, sync, canonical

As this questions says, the [Ubuntu 14.04 Software Center sync doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452291/ubuntu-14-04-software-center-sync-doesnt-work).

[Below there is a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452291/ubuntu-14-04-software-center-sync-doesnt-work#comment645235_452291) by MattiJsR:

> How will they make the sync work now that U1 is no longer available?

And my question is the same.

Is there an alternative (3rd party) to sync it? If not, will Ubuntu/Canonical bring something in to do that, in the same way just without using the U1 services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the Ubuntu One **Files** service that got shut down, not Ubuntu One plataform itself.

https://one.ubuntu.com/

Comment: But can it still sync from the software centre?

Answer (score 1):

My instinct would be that they'll change it at some point to an import/export scheme. In other words, you just have to copy an `installed.txt` from computer to computer, which is probably what Ubuntu One was doing in the background anyway.

Until they implement that in the GUI, see command-line options in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20916/syncing-apt-get-installations-between-multiple-computers). Although the question is specifically about automatic syncing, the answer by John using `dpkg` is the easiest manual method.